# How to Give Animation on Viewpager same as Coverflow?

Tags: animation, android-viewpager, coverflow

Here I am using **viewpager** and I want to give animation like cover flow. Not simple animation but same to same coverflow.
Generally I found effect on gallery but I need on **viewpager**.

```
vpPager.setPageTransformer(false, new PageTransformer() {
    @Override
    public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // page.setRotationY(position * -30);
    }
});
```

So in that `vpPager` and I need animation like coverflow
like [this](https://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow); But in that they are using gallery but I want same animation on viewpager.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Please take a [tour], and see the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Me also faced the same problem. Can anyone please provide the solution